# Get latest occurence of a date by some interval with a specific original date in history?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

For example:

Original date: 23/03/2012
Interval: every 2 weeks

Output: latest occurence -> 06/04/2012

How can I achieve this the best way in Objective-C (iOS)?

Sidenote: 
My current not so working and really bad solution:

```
+ (NSDate *) getRelativeStartDateForIntervalType:(NSInteger)intervalType andStartDateTime:(NSDate *)startDateTime {
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    BOOL found = false;
    NSDate *relativeStartDate;
    NSDate *previousDate;
    for (int i = 0; !found ; i++) {
        previousDate = relativeStartDate;

        switch (intervalType) {
            case 0:
                [components setDay:i];   // add i days
                break;
            case 1:
                [components setWeek:i];  // add i weeks
                break;
            case 2:
                [components setMonth:i]; // add i months
                break;
            case 3:
                [components setDay:i]; // add i weeks
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"you shouldn't be here");
                break;
        }
        relativeStartDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:startDateTime options:0];
        if ([relativeStartDate compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedDescending) {
            found = true;
            if (i > 0 && [previousDate compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedDescending) {
                relativeStartDate = previousDate;                
            }
        }
    }
    return  relativeStartDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For "every N weeks" or "every N days", just take the difference in days between the start date and the target date, divide by the number of days in the interval, and go back the remainder from the target date.

That is, in pseudocode, `relativeStartDate = targetDate - ((targetDate - startDate) % intervalSize)`

For "every N months", you just have to go back to the most recent occurrence of the same day of the month.  No clean way to do this other than a conditional.  If the target mday is greater than the start mday, then it's just the target date with the day of the month replaced with the day of the month of the startdate.  Otherwise, it's one month before the target date with that same substitution.

You also have to decide how to deal with days that don't exist in a given month; does one month from 31 May take you to 30 June or 1 July?